# Using facebook SDK Send Button Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sendmessage

I read the documentation of the facebook sdk. But i am not able to make the **Send Button** work. Below is the work i have done.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Bitmap image =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.cos2ms);
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .build();
        ShareContent shareContent = new ShareMediaContent.Builder()
                .addMedium(photo)

                .build();
System.out.println("Test me!!!!");
        SendButton sendButton = (SendButton)findViewById(R.id.messenger_send_button);

        sendButton.setShareContent(shareContent);

sendButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
});
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



}
```

Please i want to know how to make it work as it do nothing when i press send button it do not open the messenger to send message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way, just make sure to add this provider to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true"/>
```

also make sure to have messanger app on your device, 
you can get more information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)